# Css & asset issue with Symfony

Tags: css, symfony, twig

I wanted to take a free template to start my RolePlay forum with a "good looking" homepage; and I found this one: [Template preview](http://all-free-download.com/templates/templates_preview.php?url=http://images.all-free-download.com/free-website-templates-preview/world_of_warcraft_template_1105/)

The template himself is working fine, if I'm openning the given downloaded index.html there no problem.

Then I "translated" that page to work with my Symfony.

Here is what I got:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>
      {% block title %}Way Of Shogun {% endblock %}
    </title>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

    {% block stylesheets %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/main.css') }}" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/style.css') }}"/>
    {% endblock %}
</head>


<body>
<div id="container">
  <div id="header">
    <div id="nav">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Game Guide</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Interactive</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Account</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Support</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Media</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="content1">
    <div id="text1"> 
      <img src="{{ asset('images/cap-night-elf.gif') }}" alt="Caption" />
      <div class="heading">BEST RELEASE OF THIS MONTH</div>
      <br />
      <p>Don't forgot to check free website templates every day, because we add at least one free website template daily.</p>
      <p>This is a template designed by free website templates for you for free you can replace all the text by your own text. This is just a place holder so you can see how the site would look like.</p>
      <p>You can remove any link to our websites from this template you're  free to use the template without linking back to us. Don't want your boss to know you used a free website template ;).</p>
      <p>If you're looking for beautiful and professionally made templates you can find them at Template Beauty.</p>
      <p>
      <div class="heading">MORE GAMES</div>
      </p>
      <p> 
        <span class="flt-lft"><img src="{{ asset('images/image-1.gif') }}" alt="More Games" /></span> 
        <span class="flt-lft"><img src="{{ asset('images/image-2.gif') }}" alt="More Games" /></span> <strong>Gnome mage by Someone</strong><br />
        <br />
        Etiam ullamcorper mi eu libero bibendum consequat. Cras volutpat .<br />
        <span class="flt-rgt"><a href="#">...more</a></span> 
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="pagebottom">
    <div id="left">
      <div id="text2"> <img src="{{ asset('images/cap-community-news.gif') }}" alt="Community News" />
        <p>
        <div class="heading2">THUNDGOT, AEUS, &amp; VANERUS, 19/10/2006</div>
        </p>
        <p>Don't forgot to check free website templates every day, because we add at least one free website template daily.</p>
        <p>This is a template designed by free website templates for you for free you can replace all the text by your own text. This is just a place holder so you can see how the site would look like.</p>
        <p>You can remove any link to our websites from this template you're  free to use the template without linking back to us. Don't want your boss to know you used a free website template ;).</p>
        <p>If you're having problems editing the template please don't hesitate to ask for help on the forum.</p>
        <p>If you're looking for beautiful and professionally made templates you can find them at Template Beauty.</p>
        <p>To find great hosting providers visit Web Hosting Zoom</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


{% block body %}{% endblock %}
  <div id="right">
    <div class="heading2">QUICK LINKS</div>
    <div id="quicklinks">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Realms Status</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Account Creation</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Account Management</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Cetrieve Passward</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="heading2">SCREENSHOT OF THE DAY</div>
    <img src="{{ asset('images/screenshot.jpg') }}" alt="Screenshot" /> <br />
    <a href="#">Cross Realm Battlegrounds</a><br />
    <a href="#">World PvP </a><br />
    <a href="#">Rogue Talents revamped </a> 
  </div>

<div id="footer"> 
    <a href="#">Home</a> | <a href="#">Game Guide </a> | <a href="#">Interactive</a> | <a href="#">Community</a> | <a href="#">Account</a> | <a href="#">Support</a> | <a href="#">Media</a>
    <p>
      <a href="#">Legal Documents</a> | 
      <a href="#">Game Policies</a> 
      <br/>©2006 
      <a href="#">WorldofWarcraft.com</a>. All rights reserved. | designed by 
      <a href="http://www.freewebsitetemplates.com">free website templates</a>
    </p>
</div>
</div>
<div align=center>This template  downloaded form <a href='http://all-free-download.com/free-website-templates/'>free website templates</a></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Sorry, for the bad indentation, it's crazy to clean a code like that :(
Anyway, as I said, I've just translated to replace the images by the asset link.
But as a results, the frontend isn't the same and I can't see what's wrong.

Hope you can help me on this ;) Thanks.

Here is a screen of what I'm getting. 
To be more specific, I checked the networks calls and all the images and css and well found

[image: screen]

How it is suppose to be:
[image: render2]

Thanks again

Comment: Hi there. In order for us to be able to help you, not only will you need to include your relevant CSS in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but you'll also need to clear specify what it **should** look like in the question itself (highlighting how your code doesn't emulate that). I appreciate the desired result is probably visible in your link, but `all-free-download.com` is an awfully suspicious URL in itself, let alone the potential flags by filter systems ;)

Comment: @ObsidianAge don't worry I understand, I just added a screen of what it should be. Thanks. Hope it will be helpfull.